# Finding country from email sent

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

We are trying to set up `email services` for one of our Clients.Is it possible to find sender's country/Timezone from which the email was sent. We would use this information to route email inquiries to domestic and international Queues based on the information.

Options we have tried already

1. Usage of email Headers - The [RFC 2822](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound.htm#apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound) compliant email headers provide timezone and ip Addresses, but if the email goes via multiple SMTP servers the ip address and the time zone is not accurate anymore.
2. Usage of Einstien Intent to calculate the probability of the email being an International Inquiry

Comment: Can we ask the users the best timezone to contact them or the location, where are they from Country or state in the email? 
Other option is to roll out a template Click To Support email on the website with prefilled details using mailto:protocol and use the IP of the location where they are clicking from to fill location details.

Comment: @manjit5190  - can you expand or provide more information around mailto:protocol and how to use that to get country information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Email:**

The most reliable way would be to ask users either the best timezone to contact them or their location?

**Online Form:**

Usually the first interaction happens via an online form where you can ask user to enter country an timezone.

**If the user is already a customer**

I am sure you must be storing their contact address which you can query upon in the email service to redirect the query to appropriate timezone.

**Assuming your users will interact first time via site and will click on the link.**

Other option is to roll out a template Click To Support email on the website with prefilled details using `mailto:` protocol and use the IP of the location where they are clicking from to fill location details

On the load of the website, you can use any of the public IP tracing Sites or a proprietary one.

```
// If your site is on CloudFlare, then you can use '/cdn-cgi/trace' instead
$.get('https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

The you can use a template prefilled with this IP info something [like this](http://mailto:support%20email%20?subject=Need%20help&body=%20%20------------------------%20Please%20do%20not%20change%20this%20info%20%20IP%20ADDRESS%20:%20%3CFROM%20IP%20SERVICE%3E)

Code:

```
mailto:support email ?subject=Need help&body=

------------------------
Please do not change this info 
IP ADDRESS : <FROM IP SERVICE>
```

Still the best way would be to ask the user.